# Hover effect on circle container

Tags: html, css, rollover-effect

I have a circle with a hover effect on it and some text under. Now what I'm trying to achieve is to trigger that hover effect when you rollover the entire circle container and not only the circle itself.

**DEMO**
http://jsfiddle.net/kL0vxrxL/

```css
.icon-circle-box {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 130px;
}
.icon-circle {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 42px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 0 28px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #fff;
}
.icon-circle-box p {
  margin-top: 13px;
}
.icon-circle:after {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: '';
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
.icon-circle:before {
  font-family: 'lineicons';
  speak: none;
  font-size: 42px;
  line-height: 100px;
  display: block;
}
.circle-effect .icon-circle {
  color: #000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #000;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: color 0.3s;
  transition: color 0.3s;
}
.circle-effect .icon-circle:after {
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  padding: 2px;
  z-index: -1;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
  transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
}
.icon-circle:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
.icon-circle:hover:after {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.85);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.85);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.85);
  transform: scale(0.85);
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-circle-box circle-effect">
  <a href="#" class="icon-circle"></a>
  <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: _“Now what I'm trying to achieve is to trigger that hover effect when you rollover the entire circle container and not only the circle itself”_ – well then put `:hover` on the container and use the descendant sibling combinator …

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm trying to achieve is to trigger that hover effect when you rollover the entire circle container and not only the circle itself.

Then you would add the `:hover` pseudo-class to the parent element, `.icon-circle-box`.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/f1budhxj/)

```
.icon-circle-box:hover .icon-circle:after {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.85);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.85);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.85);
    transform: scale(0.85);
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

Comment: To the person who downvoted this, what is incorrect/wrong about this answer? How can I improve it? Did I miss something?